# if i'm given 3 points and found a vector projected onto another vector, how do i know those 3 points lie on the same line?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If i'm given 3 points and found a vector projected onto another vector, how do i know those 3 points lie on the same line?. how would i explain in terms of vector projection

Comment: Please attach the background of your question and your efforts to the question when posting.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say your points are $P,Q,R$. If the projection of $\vec{PQ}$ onto $\vec{PR}$ is identically $\vec{PQ}$, then they lie on the same line. Equivalently, you can just check if $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{PR}$ are parallel.